# how to add border for uiimage in swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, border

I have a code that adds a border to an image
And it works like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-MMrT3HinbkQXIugH99nZthdkEvDGJgH/view?usp=sharing)

but there are 2 problems when an image with a large extension is used

- sometimes the image rotates to the right
- Stroke thickness does not match the specified parameter `thickness` in `func stroked`

example [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XfnS7Sq5NCVDm3T4303NZANhXee9VZ_T/view?usp=sharing)

My code

```
public extension UIImage {

/**
Returns the flat colorized version of the image, or self when something was wrong

- Parameters:
    - color: The colors to user. By defaut, uses the ``UIColor.white`

- Returns: the flat colorized version of the image, or the self if something was wrong
*/
func colorized(with color: UIColor = .white) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)

    defer {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), let cgImage = cgImage else { return self }


    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

    color.setFill()
    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
    context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    context.clip(to: rect, mask: cgImage)
    context.fill(rect)

    guard let colored = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return self }

    return colored
}

/**
Returns the stroked version of the fransparent image with the given stroke color and the thickness.

- Parameters:
    - color: The colors to user. By defaut, uses the ``UIColor.white`
    - thickness: the thickness of the border. Default to `2`
    - quality: The number of degrees (out of 360): the smaller the best, but the slower. Defaults to `10`.

- Returns: the stroked version of the image, or self if something was wrong
*/

func stroked(with color: UIColor = .red, thickness: CGFloat = 2, quality: CGFloat = 10) -> UIImage {

    guard let cgImage = cgImage else { return self }

    // Colorize the stroke image to reflect border color
    let strokeImage = colorized(with: color)

    guard let strokeCGImage = strokeImage.cgImage else { return self }

    /// Rendering quality of the stroke
    let step = quality == 0 ? 10 : abs(quality)

    let oldRect = CGRect(x: thickness, y: thickness, width: size.width, height: size.height).integral
    let newSize = CGSize(width: size.width + 2 * thickness, height: size.height + 2 * thickness)
    let translationVector = CGPoint(x: thickness, y: 0)


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, scale)

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return self }

    defer {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: newSize.height)
    context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    context.interpolationQuality = .high

    for angle: CGFloat in stride(from: 0, to: 360, by: step) {
        let vector = translationVector.rotated(around: .zero, byDegrees: angle)
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: vector.x, y: vector.y)

        context.concatenate(transform)

        context.draw(strokeCGImage, in: oldRect)

        let resetTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -vector.x, y: -vector.y)
        context.concatenate(resetTransform)
    }

    context.draw(cgImage, in: oldRect)

    guard let stroked = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return self }

    return stroked
}
}

extension CGPoint {

- Parameters:
    - origin: The center of he rotation;
    - byDegrees: Amount of degrees to rotate around the Z axis.

- Returns: The rotated point.
*/
func rotated(around origin: CGPoint, byDegrees: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    let dx = x - origin.x
    let dy = y - origin.y
    let radius = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
    let azimuth = atan2(dy, dx) // in radians
    let newAzimuth = azimuth + byDegrees * .pi / 180.0 // to radians
    let x = origin.x + radius * cos(newAzimuth)
    let y = origin.y + radius * sin(newAzimuth)
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}
```

}